# How to use angular translate on ng-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, ng-dropdown-multiselect

In my AngularJS app, I used angular translate to implement internationalization.

But it doesn't work with `ng-dropdown-multiselect` texts.

I tried to associate  translation-texts with $scope variables and apply $scope.$watch to wait changes, but it not worked too.

Someone knows how make it multi-language?

```
<div
    ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
    options="myModelOptions" 
    selected-model="mySelectedItem" 
    extra-settings="mySettings" 
    translation-texts="{
        'checkAll': myScopeVariable.selectAll,
        'uncheckAll': myScopeVariable.selectNone,
        'buttonDefaultText': myScopeVariable.selectZero,
        'selectionCount': myScopeVariable.selectCount,
        'dynamicButtonTextSuffix': myScopeVariable.selectSufix
    }">
</div>
```

Comment: how do you set myScopeVariable in your controller?

Comment: it's just a example, I'm using on this way: $scope.myScopeVar... got it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to watch a scope, the `translation-texts` attributes they provided works only during building the dom.
You can use a trick by rebuilding the select for everytime you change a language.

1- Adding condition for displaying the select, for this example `ng-if="!unready"`.
And use the `translate` filter directly.

```
<div ng-if="!unready" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="cars" selected-model="selectedCar" extra-settings="mySettings" translation-texts="{
        'checkAll': ('selectAll' | translate),
        'uncheckAll': ('selectNone' | translate),
        'buttonDefaultText': ('selectZero' | translate),
        'selectionCount': ('selectCount' | translate),
        'dynamicButtonTextSuffix': ('selectSufix' | translate)
    }">
  </div>
```

2- catch the language change detection if the button changing it is not in the same controller, and set the variable to not display the select, adding a little timeout to display it again so the select will be re-rendered.

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        // Language has changed
        $scope.unready = true;
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.unready = false;
        }, 10);
    });
```

A working plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/2psHUD/